# AngularJS disable partial caching on dev machine

Tags: caching, angularjs, browser-cache

I have problem with caching partials in AngularJS.

In my HTML page I have:

```
<body>
 <div ng-view></div>
<body>
```

where my partials are loaded.

When I change HTML code in my partial, browser still load old data.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Just a quick note: I had a problem with this that was more related to the cache control headers my Flask application was sending back. I got around the issue by adding `app.config.update(SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT=0)` to my `flask_app.py`. (I imagine similar things exist for other web servers).

Comment: If you're using chrome just do a `Ctrl+Shift+R` (i.e. Hard Reload) and no matter what caching mechanism is used chrome will ignore it and re-fetch all the scripts, stylesheets etc.

Comment: ctrl+shift+R doesn't work for me in Chrome, but on the developer tools "network" tab, clicking on "disable cache" works perfectly. For me, this is a client side problem which shouldn't be solved using hacks on the server like many of the suggestions below; it should be fixed on the client where the "problem" exists.  If you fix it on the server, and forget to un-fix it, production could be adversely affected.

Comment: ctrl+shift+R bypasses cache for normal requests. ajax requests made from angular for `ng-include`|`ng-view`|`templateUrl` are not handled by this shortcut

Comment: You can't ask all end users to Ctrl+Shift+R when visiting the site, so what's the answer to this question for the non development case?  "For me, this is a client side problem which shouldn't be solved using hacks on the server like many of the suggestions below" - I don't agree, you can't control clients in a web environment so the fix for production must be application driven.  For that reason I accepted: $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
   });

Answer (score 200, accepted):

For Development you can also deactivate the browser cache - In Chrome Dev Tools on the bottom right click on the gear and tick the option

> Disable cache (while DevTools is open)

Update: In Firefox there is the same option in Debugger -> Settings -> Advanced Section (checked for Version 33)

Update 2: Although this option appears in Firefox some report it doesn't work. I suggest using firebug and following hadaytullah answer.

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer because it doesn't require a code change, and is more to the point of the OP's request.  Of course you would want a production app to cache requests, so doing what the above folks suggested, while well meaning, could prove problematic if the code is left in a production app.

Comment: Any suggestions for the other browsers like Firefox?

Comment: In Firefox: Debugger > Settings (the gear) there is the same option.

Comment: This does not work in Firefox.  Even when cache is disabled, and the toolbox is open, the templates are still cached.

Comment: Does caching affect production too? What if I push new web files to the server, what prevents subsequent requests from production clients from loading a pre-published cached versions?

Comment: `ctrl + shift + r` for chrome

Comment: @PatrickJCollins Had the same problem in firefox. I solved by going to Menu: History > Clear Recent History and select 1 hour and only check "Cache". Not a nice solution of course.

Answer (score 112):

Building on @Valentyn's answer a bit, here's one way to always automatically clear the cache whenever the ng-view content changes:

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
   });
});
```

Comment: @user252690 Probably also need to make sure html template was not sent with cache headers. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine#answer-22359241) and 
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine#comments-14718826) for possible fixes

Comment: **A bit of a warning:** Emptying the $templateCache might actually have unintended consequences. For instance, [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) adds default partials directly to the $templateCache during initialization and later expects them to be there.

Comment: @Strille I was trying to use angular-ui-bootstrap Modal. The pop up was not visible. because  $templateCache.removeAll(); any fix for it ?

Comment: @Mukun: There's no easy fix the way I see it, other than not using removeAll() but instead just use remove() to delete the keys you need to clear. You would require some kind of bookkeeping to know which keys to delete.

Comment: is there any ways to clear cache only for specific ui view cache.

Comment: How would this look like for Angular 2?

Answer (score 38):

As mentioned in the other answers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine#answer-14721340) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine#answer-14719200), the cache can be cleared by using:

```
$templateCache.removeAll();
```

However as suggested by [gatoatigrado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81636/gatoatigrado) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine#comments-14718826), this only appears to work if the html template was served without any cache headers.

So this works for me:

In angular:

```
app.run(['$templateCache', function ( $templateCache ) {
    $templateCache.removeAll(); }]);
```

You may be adding cache headers in a variety of ways but here are a couple of solutions that work for me.

If using `IIS`, add this to your web.config:

```
<location path="scripts/app/views">
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

If using Nginx, you can add this to your config:

```
location ^~ /scripts/app/views/ {
    expires -1;   
}
```

**Edit**

I just realised that the question mentioned `dev` machine but hopefully this may still help somebody...

Comment: yes, even though this doesn't answer original question directly this did in fact help me solve the caching issue on a live website.

Answer (score 31):

If you are talking about cache that is been used for caching of templates without reloading whole page, then you can empty it by something like:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $templateCache) {
  $scope.clearCache = function() { 
    $templateCache.removeAll();
  }
});
```

And in markup:

`<button ng-click='clearCache()'>Clear cache</button>`

And press this button to clear cache.

Answer (score 22):

### Solution For Firefox (33.1.1) using Firebug (22.0.6)

1. Tools > Web-Tools > Firebug > Open Firebug.
2. In the Firebug views go to the "Net" view.
3. A drop down menu symbol will appear next to "Net" (title of the view).
4. Select "Disable Browser Cache" from the drop down menu.

Comment: Tried on Firebug (2.0.11) and Firefox (38.0.1) on mac but this did not work.

Answer (score 19):

This snippet helped me in getting rid of template caching

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

The details of following snippet can be found on this link:
http://oncodesign.io/2014/02/19/safely-prevent-template-caching-in-angularjs/

Comment: nitpick but when is current ever not an object? Not sure it's ever not there either but
`if (!current) { return; }`

Comment: This defeats Angular's caching of route-based templates, but not ng-include'd partials.

Answer (score 17):

I'm posting this just to cover all possibilities since neither of the other solutions worked for me (they threw errors due angular-bootstrap template dependencies, among others).

While you are developing/debugging a specific template, you can ensure it always refreshes by included a timestamp in the path, like this:

```
       $modal.open({
          // TODO: Only while dev/debug. Remove later.
          templateUrl: 'core/admin/organizations/modal-selector/modal-selector.html?nd=' + Date.now(),
          controller : function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.ok = function () {
              $modalInstance.close();
            };
          }
        });
```

Note the final `?nd=' + Date.now()` in the `templateUrl` variable.

Comment: Later you can set a `.value('DEBUG', true)` to enable that line or not.

Comment: My Solution was to use the following within the initialization phase of my main module under `.run(function($rootScope) { $rootScope.DEBUG = true; ...` and then within the the directive inject the $rootScope like `.directive('filter', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)...` and in the returned object-property: `templateUrl: '/app/components/filter/filter-template.html' + ($rootScope.DEBUG ? '?n=' + Date.now() : '')`. Maybe you could elaborate your .value('DEBUG', true) approach? Upvoted!

Comment: The use of  `.value('DEBUG', true` is the same as you did with `$rootScope`, but without cluttering it :) You could later inject `DEBUG` into the controller and query as a normal service.

Comment: Could you maybe extend the sourcecode in your answer to include the `.value(...)` thingy, if it's not too sophisticated? I suppose the concept behind is an angular best-practice unknown to me.

Comment: This solution is very useful when working with Ionic. It's gonna save me so much time as it makes livereload useful again. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks that saved me. In controller I have `$scope.cacheKiller = '?nd=' + Date.now();` and in template `<ng-include src="'partials/' + tabs[currentTab].template + '.html' + cacheKiller"></ng-include>`.

Comment: hm, i used this solution but it leaves me wondering, why such a pain? Why can't the browser tell that template was changed?

Answer (score 11):

As others have said, defeating caching completely for dev purposes can be done easily without changing code: use a browser setting or a plugin.  Outside of dev, to defeat Angular template caching of route-based templates, remove the template URL from the cache during $routeChangeStart (or $stateChangeStart, for UI Router) as Shayan showed.  However, that does NOT affect the caching of templates loaded by ng-include, because those templates are not loaded through the router.

I wanted to be able to hotfix any template, including those loaded by ng-include, in production and have users receive the hotfix in their browser quickly, without having to reload the entire page. I'm also not concerned about defeating HTTP caching for templates. The solution is to intercept every HTTP request that the app makes, ignore those that are not for my app's .html templates, then add a param to the template's URL that changes every minute. Note that the path-checking is specific to the path of your app's templates. To get a different interval, change the math for the param, or remove the % completely to get no caching.

```
// this defeats Angular's $templateCache on a 1-minute interval
// as a side-effect it also defeats HTTP (browser) caching
angular.module('myApp').config(function($httpProvider, ...) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                config.url = getTimeVersionedUrl(config.url);
                return config;
            }
        };
    });

    function getTimeVersionedUrl(url) {
        // only do for html templates of this app
        // NOTE: the path to test for is app dependent!
        if (!url || url.indexOf('a/app/') < 0 || url.indexOf('.html') < 0) return url;
        // create a URL param that changes every minute
        // and add it intelligently to the template's previous url
        var param = 'v=' + ~~(Date.now() / 60000) % 10000; // 4 unique digits every minute
        if (url.indexOf('?') > 0) {
            if (url.indexOf('v=') > 0) return url.replace(/v=[0-9](4)/, param);
            return url + '&' + param;
        }
        return url + '?' + param;
    }
```

Comment: I am interested in your solution - do you keep this code in for good - or a for a certain period of time after you make a change? Reason - would be concerned about performance. Also, you mention side-effect defeats HTTP. You mean that is a good side-effect way correct - meaning that is what you intended in order to have 'hotfix'?Thx

Comment: I do leave this code in for good, though we dialed back the length of cache-busting to 10 minutes. So in every 10 minutes of use, a user will be reloading fresh html templates. For my biz app that is an acceptable cost to gain the ability to hot-patch templates, but obviously it would impair performance too much for some kinds of apps. ... It is unfortunate that HTTP caching is defeated as well, but I don't see a way to intelligently defeat Angular template caching without defeating etag's etc as well. IMO Angular template caching is just not configurable enough.

Comment: +1 I had the same idea, but I only intercept for localhost. You can see my implementation of the interceptor here:
http://overengineer.net/preventing-angularjs-from-caching-your-templates-and-other-files

Comment: @joshcomley If you only need to defeat caching on localhost, why not use a browser plugin that defeats all caching?

Comment: @bradw2k this way I am in complete control of what is and isn't cached, which can be useful for development. I also test in all browsers, and not all browsers have extensions that do what I need. I can also have an indicator on the site in development telling me whether or not caching is disabled, as sometimes I only want to disable and test across browsers for a while.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using UI router then you can use a decorator and update $templateFactory service and append a query string parameter to templateUrl, and the browser will always load the new template from the server.

```
function configureTemplateFactory($provide) {
    // Set a suffix outside the decorator function 
    var cacheBust = Date.now().toString();

    function templateFactoryDecorator($delegate) {
        var fromUrl = angular.bind($delegate, $delegate.fromUrl);
        $delegate.fromUrl = function (url, params) {
            if (url !== null && angular.isDefined(url) && angular.isString(url)) {
                url += (url.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&");
                url += "v=" + cacheBust;
            }

            return fromUrl(url, params);
        };

        return $delegate;
    }

    $provide.decorator('$templateFactory', ['$delegate', templateFactoryDecorator]);
}

app.config(['$provide', configureTemplateFactory]);
```

I am sure you can achieve the same result by decorating the "when" method in $routeProvider.

Comment: A much better alternative is to use a plugin like gulp-angular-templatecache to register angular js templates in the $templateCache. This should be used along with gulp-rev. Everytime a template changes, a new JavaScript file with a different revision number will be created and caching will never be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the HTTP interceptor method works pretty nicely, and allows additional flexibility & control. Additionally, you can cache-bust for each production release by using a release hash as the buster variable.

Here is what the dev cachebusting method looks like using `Date`.

```
app.factory('cachebustInjector', function(conf) {   
    var cachebustInjector = {
        request: function(config) {    
            // new timestamp will be appended to each new partial .html request to prevent caching in a dev environment               
            var buster = new Date().getTime();

            if (config.url.indexOf('static/angular_templates') > -1) {
                config.url += ['?v=', buster].join('');
            }
            return config;
        }
    };
    return cachebustInjector;
});

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('cachebustInjector');
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option in Chrome.

Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to open developer tools.  Then **Resources** > **Cache Storage** > **Refresh Caches**.

[image]

I like this option because I don't have to disable cache as in other answers.

Comment: In Chrome v. 54.0.2840.99 in November 2016 I found this on a tab called Application.rather than Resources.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to prevent browser/proxy caching since you cannot have the control on it.

The other way to force fresh content to your users it to rename the HTML file! Exactly like https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-filerev does for assets.