# Caching Profile CacheForTimePeriod Not Working Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, caching, web-config

In my web.config I have staticContent clientCache and it works perfectly.

However, I wanted more specific cache based on the different types of file extension. So I'm trying to accomplish this using the Caching Profiles.

```
<add extension=".js"  policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" duration="00:10:00" location="Downstream" varyByQueryString="*"/>
```

With staticContent - clientCache, I can look at the headers and it returns a "Cache-Control:max-age=600". However, with my Caching Profiles.. it doesn't work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I see you did not get any help...

Comment: Jeremy, my particular use case was to handle JavaScript files and I do not recommend this in the slightest for js files.

What's the use case you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Using Angular and did not want to cache the .html templates.  Angular has it's own caching technique for this.  I want them to reload each time the application runs.  Did not want to affect my .css and .js files.

Comment: Ah, who hasn't ran into this annoyance? Most people warn to be careful about blocking the caching as it makes things faster for us, but I have had issues and done something like this:

templateUrl: 'modaltpl.html?d=' + Date.now()

and in IIS..
<location path="js/views">
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</location>

Comment: Actually check out: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine

Comment: Thanks man, going read it now.  In my case (this time) it is an internal application. I just put an 8 hour expiration on all static content and moved on.  If they want a fix it will be ready tomorrow :)

Comment: Always happy to help. :)