# prevent certain states from caching in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, caching, angular-ui-router

I am writing a small shopping application using angularJS. I would like to be able to prevent the templates of certain `$states` from caching, e.g. the order review state. My problem is that a user may change an order and then use the browser-next-button to go to the order review page. The page loads a template with some server-prepared shopping cart data.

I'd be fine with the templates of other states (like a product description state) to be cachable. Therefore I would not want to use `$templateCache.removeAll();`.

On https://gist.github.com/claudemamo/9092047#file-app-2-js I've found this:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

where I would probably just do something similar every time the state changes for all the states I don't want to be cached.

Should I just check which template I am loading and then remove it from the cache if I don't want it to be cached?

Comment: Would this Q/A help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589843/disable-template-caching-in-angularjs-with-ui-router

Comment: The question is not clear.  You ask about caching states but the example code is about template caches.

Comment: @SteveCampbell I've clarified the question, as it was unclear. As now stated above, I want to prevent the templates of specific states from being cached.