# JHipster CachingHttpHeadersFilter timeToLive settings and production releases

Tags: browser-cache, jhipster

I'm using JHipster 2.27.2

When doing production releases I've noticed that due to the Http Headers set by the CachingHttpHeadersFilter that old html templates (i.e. the html templates referenced in the ui-router states) are hanging around.  Obviously the users can manually clear the browser cache, but this is not always practical when dealing with a large group of unknown users.

Besides removing the html caching entirely either by setting the timeToLiveInDays to zero or changing the cachebuster settings in the app.js file to include html templates, is there another way to take advantage of html file caching but at the sametime ensuring that the user's html files stay fresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static assets (images, css, ..) are versioned by the frontend build process (see [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev)) to avoid caching stale assets. I don't think HTML templates are versioned (2.x is rather old version) but angular loads them using XHR so cache buster should work for them.

For other HTML files, you may want to look at WebConfigurer#initCachingHttpHeadersFilter() to see which URL patterns it uses and store these other HTML files under different folders or adjust the patterns to exclude them.

Comment: Does JHipster 3 version the html templates?  If so is there an old pull request that I can reference?

Comment: I don't think so, things might change with JHipster 4 using Angular 2 and webpack for bundling frontend code. But as I explained in my answer, for angular HTML templates this should not be needed, so could you clarify your use case? Are you talking about HTML templates/fragments referenced by angular ui-router states or other HTML pages similar to index.html?

Comment: Hi Gael, I've updated the question to specify the html templates as these are the ones I'm having issues with.

Comment: Then cache busting approach should work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589843/disable-template-caching-in-angularjs-with-ui-router