# Refreshing html changes on Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I upload changes in my html partial files of AngularJS there is a cache and the old data is shown. Just after a couple of refresh actions the changes are shown.

How can I make the changes available immediately?

Comment: do you mean while you are developing and checking it in browser your browser cache's the resources ?

Comment: did you use $scope.$apply when updating scope?

Comment: Maybe this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine

Comment: I mean that case that I changed html code and uploaded it to production. It displays the old data though the uploading and just after couple of refreshes the new version is shown.

Comment: @user1279647 Someone wrote that it doesn't work.

Comment: @KhanhTO - not always.

Answer (score 2):

if you are on chrome browser go to devTools F12

then click on the gear icon on the left and then tick "Disable cache(while DevTools is open)

Comment: It's not comprehensive solution.

Comment: well as i understood it is not refreshing to the new markup in your html partial files , you need this to bypass caching while you are developing since once deployed partials markup will not change , or is the issue it is not getting the latest data from the model ?

Comment: if it is data thing then maybe it is something related to your webserver caching

Comment: No. It's not just about my browser. There is not an issue with the data from server but the static html.