# Changes not reflected when refreshing angularjs page

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to look at Angularjs (going through Code School demo).

When I make changes to the template they are not reflected when refreshing in the browser. I have tried:

- hard refreshing (and confirmed code 200 in the apache log)
- deleting the browser cache (firefox)
- Renaming the file on the server.
- Opening in a different browser

  However, copying the file to a new name on the server DOES have the changes be reflected.

regular HTML files that do not include the angular library update as normal.

Making a change to the javascript is reflected immediately (e.g. adding an alert('test')).

Is there something fundamental that I am missing here?

EDIT - Environment Details
Running on a Centos6.6 virtual box (Virtualbox) on a mac OS 10.10. Document room is /var/www/dev which is a symbolic link to /mnt/dev which I have mounted via the VirtualBox tools so I can edit the file directly on my mac
the VM config
Listen 10001

```
NameVirtualHost *:10001
<VirtualHost *:10001>

DocumentRoot /var/www/dev
    <Directory />
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @uowzd01 I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be a vboxsf issue as per the issue below. The changes made to the filesystem were not getting servered by apache.

> https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/issues/315

Workaround: Turn sendfile off in httpd.conf

```
EnableSendfile off
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine) and see if the firefox answer by @hadaytullah solves your issues. I would also try it in Chrome.  Probably using Angular's [template caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) somewhere.

Comment: You can fully disable the template cache via: http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.com/2014/02/safely-prevent-template-caching-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Tried in Chrome and it just gives the latest verison that was also visible in Firefox so it leads me to believe this is a AnglularJS level caching somewhere but I have no idea how to turn it off. I tried @hadaytullah 's answer but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The only way it worked for was this: 
Go to firefox menu -> preferences -> advanced -> Network -> under Cached Web Content click on Clear Now.