# Undetectable caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, caching, angular-ui-router

I'm a web app developer with `ASP.NET MVC 5` in `server-side` and `AngularJS` in client-side. The navigation, in client-side, is managed with module UI-Router. In server-side I've configured my custom authentication and authorization. When I excecute the app can see a navigation bar with many links. In particular, I have a link named "Overview" that redirects to controller Overview.

Code client (html):

```
<a ui-sref="Overview">Overview</a>
```

Code client to redirect (angular):

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("Home/Index");
     $stateProvider
        .state("Overview", {
            templateUrl: "Home/Overview",
            url: "/overview"
        })
```

Controller code:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=0, NoStore=true)]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Overview()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

With a breakpoint in line `"return PartialView()"` to `controller` code, I can see that `controller` returns partial view when I click over "overview" in menu app. But when I click second time, the breakpoint does not trigger. I think it's a caching issue.

I have read that caching issue can be generated:
 * In server-side.
 * In client-side.
 * Even IIS.

I have tried many solutions: In server side I use `attribute [OutputCache]`.
When i read in my browser the http headers i can see

[image]

In client side i could not find a solution to avoid caching, but i think that UI-Router shouldn't cache anything.

As additional measures I put in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

even, I created my own custom `ActionFilterAttribute` but did not work.

i don't know what else to do.

PS: sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is any other plugin which does caches its templates, then your solution will clean those templates and make those plugins unusable.. hence your solution is not good.

To solve problem of html caching you should add random query string at the end of html filename... the other solutions you mentioned are for non-caching of api responses and not for static content (html/js/css files)

To add random query string to ur html. either you can use modules like [grunt-cache-busting](https://github.com/PaulTondeur/grunt-cache-busting) or [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev) or use query string as param [query-string-cache-busting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params).

Please note that datetime/file-hash are best cache-busting param

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution.

Despite avoid caching from server side with attributes like `OutputCache`, or avoid caching from IIS setting my web.config, the issue persisted.

AngularJS was the guilty. [In other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine) I found the solution.

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        $templateCache.removeAll();
    });
});
```

This solution is provided by Mark Rajcok and Valentyn Shybanov. So thanks to both.

Comment: @entre I have not checked the question as correct so you can explain. I know that this solution can be inconsistent with UI-bootstrap. [This solution](http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/safely-prevent-template-caching-in-angularjs.html) seems to solve, but don't work for me.

Comment: exactly.. if there is any other plugin which does caches its templates, then this solution will clean those templates and make those plugins unusable.. to solve problem of html caching you should add random query string at its end... the solution you mentioned are for non-caching of api responses and not for static contents

Comment: so I can put a random query string to avoid cache, and does not query string make plugin unusable?

Comment: no just add random query string to only ur html. to do that either you can use modules like [grunt-cache-busting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cache-busting) or use query string as param [query-string-cache-busting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params) or datetime as params which is best cache-busting param

Comment: if you are using gulp look at [this](https://github.com/bustardcelly/gulp-rev-append)

Comment: You've given me guidance very well!. Thanks for your help.

Comment: putting my comments as an answer