# Versioning an Angular 2 App

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

How can one mark versions of an Angular 2 app?

There are some problems like views (via `templateUrl`) are not getting updated in route views (child components). I've tried things like

```
<script>
    System.config({
        // baseURL: '/',
        packages: {        
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('v1/app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Or `app/v1/boot` and playing with `base` but it's not working.

**Note:** Just for the record, at development time, cached templates (introduces via `templateUrl`) do annoyingly slow things. One should use incognito sessions or clear up the browser and the like. I've solved this by introducing a global var in a module like `export var fileVersion = '?tmplv=' + Date.now();` and use it in components like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: '/app/templates/my-component.html' + fileVersion,
})
```

So I have just to refresh the browser to see the changes. In production use either `fileVersion = '';` or like `export var fileVersion = '?tmplv=v3';`.

Comment: Not an answer, but I use the `disable cache` feature in the `Network` tab of chrome which loads each template fresh each time. Note: This **only** works when the Developer Tools are open.

Comment: Thanks; the problem is how to version the app in production? Like when a user is visiting the website (the app) & we need to deploy a new version that fixes something.

Comment: CDN's and I don't believe that caches last forever. There is a limited TTL and it will fetch anew.

Comment: I am using a CDN and it is still a problem. The HTML and the JS are not updated at the same time and causes errors.

Answer (score 1):

I am dealing with the same issue. 
I am looking for something like filerev Node package. 
For now, my solution is to use angular 2 to clear the cache:

First import the RuntimeCompiler.

`import { RuntimeCompiler} from '@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler';`

Next inject the RuntimeCompiler in your constructor.

`constructor(private _runtimeCompiler: RuntimeCompiler)`
Finally use that to clear the cache. Note this clears all templates.

`this._runtimeCompiler.clearCache();`