# Angular2, prevent view caching in any browser

Tags: angular, angular2-template

All,

Is it possible to prevent caching of views in Angular2?

With angular 1.x it was easy to modifier the headers to prevent such things using $httpProvider but i don't see anything similar in angular2.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808023/how-to-clear-template-cache-angular-js-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to do that:

- **Option #1**: use the `BaseRequestOptions` class

You could extend this class and set the header to use for each request:

```
@Injectable()
export class DefaultRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions{
    headers:Headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
}
```

And registers it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,[
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide( RequestOptions, { useClass: DefaultRequestOptions })
});
```

- **Option #2**: extend the `Http` class itself

You could also extend the `Http` class and set the headers you want in it, as described below:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options);        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    // Add headers into options
    (...)
    return super.get(url, options);
  }

  (...)
}
```

And registers it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(Http, {
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```