# How to disable template cacheing in Angular2

Tags: caching, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

Is there any way to disable template cache in Angular 2 ?

I'm creating one single page application in Angular2.My App have three page. So i use Route to switch from one page to another.In one of my page i have a submit button.I need to disable it based on values selected by user. My issue is that Once i make it disabled  it will remain disabled until i refresh the page.It will not enable when i go back to come to same page. This is because of Template caching . Html page is not reloading once it loaded.

Is there any way to disable cache or reload template ?

Thanks

Comment: See [routerCanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed now. Caching is occurred due to angular 2 beta.0 version. Now I updated it to beta.13. It's working now.

Answer (score -3):

Please try the following links that address your question:

[AngularJS disable partial caching on dev machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine)

[How to clear template cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808023/how-to-clear-template-cache-angular-js-2-0)

Alternatively you can try this code:

```
...

app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!