# Angular 2 html caching issue

Tags: angular

I am working on the angular 2 application. I just started the application and as its new technology, I am not aware of lot of the things. I successfully created the template and added component like header, footer, navigation etc. The issue is that once I add the component and remove it the rendered page still shows that component on the page. I googled for the issue and people are suggesting that I need to use `APP_VIEW_POOL_CAPACITY` but I am not sure how and where to use it ? if you guys help and If you can provide me plunker then it would be great help.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 (Chrome) fixes it?

Comment: No, Ctrl+F5 is not working. even I also tried in incognito mode.

Comment: Sounds like a server issue then.

Comment: @user3739018 you're the one who has to provide a plnkr. Besides that `APP_VIEW_POOL_CAPACITY` was removed in beta.1

Comment: clear the cache manually may fix your problem by pressing `Ctrl+shift+del` and press `clear now` button in `FF`. Similar way in different browsers.

Comment: for development you can just use 'disable cache checkbox' in Chrome console (network tab), for production I use angular-webpack-starter https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter. Tell me if you need detailed explanation

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808023/how-to-clear-template-cache

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear template cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808023/how-to-clear-template-cache)