# Force HTML template reload in Angular2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular

I am working on Angular2 project and got an issue that Chrome caches HTML templates. It is not a problem for the development since I can make cache to be ignored in Chrome Dev mode.

But it is a real pain for the customer and his users...
I tried to add following to templateURL:

```
templateUrl: './pages/add-financial-deal.html?v=201610070907',
```

Updated URL is added into auto-generated JS but Chrome still uses cached JS even if I click Shift + F5. Checkout screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/bc2nf4zVcm

Is there any reliable way to get it working?

Thanks

**Edit: Decmber 2nd**

I have finally figured out what happening there. Despite the fact that I have added changes into TS (and auto-generated JS was also updated) Chrome is still loading file from in-memory cache - screencast.com/t/FGuaMXaKL . I have been waiting for 30 mins, but it still loads in-memory cached file. Is it intended behavior? How to avoid this?

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808023/how-to-clear-template-cache-angular-js-2-0, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849122/angular2-refresh-component-template/39850540#39850540

Comment: Not really I think...I don't need all templates reload. And it seems that I don't need HTML reload but JS reload.

Comment: I think I have fixed my issue by adding "applicationCache.update();". Doing more testing now....

Comment: appending "?v=....." to template url partially resolved an issue. At the moment I have another issue not related to Angular2 itself. Chrome caches JS ! And shift + F5 doesn't help

Comment: What about Ctrl+F5?

Comment: I have finally figured out what happening there. Despite the fact that I have added changes into TS (and auto-generated JS was also updated) Chrome is still loading file from in-memory cache - http://www.screencast.com/t/FGuaMXaKL . I have been waiting for 30 mins, but it still loads in-memory cached file. Is it intended behavior? How to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+F5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally fixed an issue which was actually 2 issues:

1. HTML templates were cached. This was fixed by adding extra parameter into template URL, like "template.html?v=201612041641"
2. JS files were staying in Chrome in-memory cache. Despite the fact that it should be kinda fast cache JS were cached for hours and hours. And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> does not affect in-memory cache. Also, I tried to set cache control to "no-store, no-cache" in root html page. Finally, I set extra header into IIS Response header option "Control-Cache:no-cache" and now it works. JS files are stored on hard drive Chtome store, 304 status is recieved and changed files are properly updated