# Angular2 Web App - Always loads the cached version

Tags: angular

I have an `angular2` web app. Every time I make changes to it, I deploy it on a dev server using cPanel.

I build the app using `ng build --env=prod` and then copy the contents of the `dist` folder.

However, when I access the site, it always loads the old version. I have to clear my cache, only then does it load the latest version.

How can I fix this, so that, the latest version is loaded (but, if there is no change, then the cached copy can be loaded)?

Comment: Cache can be persisted at many locations (server, network, and browser). You have to figure which location(s) has the cached copy and then figure out how to clear it based on that. You also did not mention where you clear your cache from.

Comment: Use --prod. Not just --env=prod. That will use AOT, minify your bundles, and generate unique bundle names.

Comment: @Aravind So, you would be happy if, every time you would go to an some web site, you saw the version of the site from 2002 instead of the newest version? How is that a useless question?

Comment: @Igor - I am clearing the browser cache, after which it loads the latest version.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Thanks! I will do that.

Comment: Have you seen this answer yet? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36585119/1260204

Comment: @Aravind - Of course I don't want to NOT cache it. But if there is a new version, I would definitely want it to load the latest. So I disagree with you.