# Clear cache / Reload templateUrl

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I need to reload the template when I do `this.state.reload();`.

According to [Angular Compiler documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler) and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40156489/6835976) I should do `compiler.clearCache();` but it doesn't seem to work. You can see from the Network tab of your browser that no new request is made after the initials.

I have also added `templateUrl: 'templateUrl?v='+(new Date().getTime())` but template is loaded only the first time.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/vvliI4?p=preview) using Angular v.4.2.5 and UIRouter v.1.0.0-beta.7
Any ideas how to accomplish this?

[I also opened a github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17880#issuecomment-312921639) since this may be a bug.

Comment: Same problem, and i'm using window.location.reload() to work around this.