# Fire store issue after hosting firebase angular 5 project from submit

Tags: angular, firebase, cache-control, firebase-hosting

I'am working with angular 5 + firebase project .I have an issue with firestore when adding new data to collection after hosting my project .

I have a form to submit ; in local environment it works very well but after deploying (hosting) my project it work the first time i open url project but for the second time it didnt work (only if i clean browser cache (CTRL+F5)) . No error in console is displayed .

Request to firestore keep pending then cancelled : Request initator is  polyfill.bundle.js file in local environment the initiator is zone.js file
[After hosting project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3iGX.png)

I need some help to avoid this problem
Thanks

Comment: "second time it didnt work".. not work the forms, only a specific form or all project? Are you using formgroup or something?

Comment: Try clear cache before deploy like  this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585119/4654957

Comment: thanks for your answer , I am using form group and all form in project didnt work second time : second time it means that i close navigator and i re open then i submit form

Comment: hmm... Are your form group using some API WS or loading some data of database? After submit successful put this.yourFormName.reset(); test please.

Comment: i'm using firestore as Db and form is for registration no API WS used . Same problem after adding reset on success of form submit , second time reset is not fired because the request is canceled as shown in the screen shot  . I think it's related to configuration file "firebase.json" because this behavior is only after hosting my project

Comment: it was a cache problem with service worker in my app which is activated only after hosting the project . i disable it and now forms work fine . i will try to figure a way to keep using service worker and avoid this issue