# Chrome keeps loading page from Cache

Tags: angular, google-chrome

For some reason, chrome keeps loading index.html from cache. In network tab of developers tool, I get 200 Ok (loaded from disk cache). When I disable cache or clear cache, then it loads fresh copy of index.html. But the issue doesn't happen in other browsers (e.g. edge).What am I doing wrong? How do I force chrome not to use cache at all and always fetch fresh copy just like it would when I hit F5? Here's my html.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
</head>
```

Comment: I have tried putting just content="no-store" for cache-control. No luck

Comment: Write a http interceptor and before your get the service call `window.location.reload(true);` it will remove the cache and reload the page.

Comment: For obvious reasons, location.reload(), refreshes the page, Also check this post there are [few ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808023/how-to-clear-template-cache), might be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Open the developer toolbar by `ctrl` + `shift` + `I`.

Goto Application -> clear storage. Click on Clear site data(Tick all checkbox).

This is happening because of the `service worker`

Comment: Thanks Omkar. Yes it works when i clear the cache as you said. But, I need to fix it in application code so that user doesn’t have to perform clear cache. Can you please explain about service worker?

Comment: @Praati enable service worker when it is production env. `ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })`
Read more at:  https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started