# How to clear the cache in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing an angular project,but after every changes in java-script file I want to clear the cache.So I want to know is there any angular code for deleting or removing the cache file?

Comment: maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32414/492258)

Answer (score 30):

just do this `npm cache clear --force` it will work

Answer (score 9):

Just move ahead with the following command

```
npm cache clear --force
```

For verifying, you can run the following command to check the contents of the cache folder, garbage collecting any unneeded data, and verifying the integrity of the cache index and all cached data.

```
npm cache verify
```

Comment: A question can have multiple answers even though it was same. It's all about how it is being explained.

Comment: That's why we have the edit button. If you you think you can enrich the given answer, then make a suggestion. That's how SO works

Comment: That's your way of approach, What I did was elaborated the answer in my own way and made simple

Answer (score 3):

first

```
npm cache clear --force
```

then

```
npm cache verify
```

Answer (score 3):

How about adding this tag to index.html ? Is this valid?

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />  
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />  
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: This works for HTML changes that don't appear until after clearing cache.
Here's a great article that explains it well: 
"For a single-page web application like Angular, index.html is like a gate for everything else. In Angular and almost all the other single-page web applications, routing happens in the front-end. Basically, by loading index.html, we are loading all the other pages too (If not lazy-load). Hence, If index.html is cached, then every other page is cached as well."
http://yuezhizizhang.github.io/angular6/cache-control/2019/06/07/angular-cache-control.html

Answer (score 3):

1'st Step:

`npm cache clear --force`

2'nd Step:

`npm cache verify`