# Angular JS error angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, node.js

While loading my index.html i am facing this error

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>Testing
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js" ></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
   $scope.submit= function(){
var data = {
  book: {            
    author: $scope.author,
    title : $scope.title,
    body : $scope.body
  }
}

$http.post("/", data).success(function(data, status) {
    console.log('Data posted successfully');
})
   }
});
</script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">    
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
      Author:
      <input type="text" ng-model="author">
      <br>
      <br> Title:
      <input type="text" ng-model="title">
      <br>
      <br> Body:
      <input type="author" ng-model="body">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit()">
    </form>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I am running it on my node.js code which is

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + './public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body)
    res.sendFile(__dirname +'/index1.html');
});

console.log('server running at 3000!')
app.listen(3000);
```

I am getting index.html correctly but in google chrome inspection it is showing me error

> angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)

Comment: i think you have to load javascript library file, please check

Comment: Hey Ashish Which javascript file should I load?

Comment: I've included angular.min.js already @AshishPatel

Comment: <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script> you can either download library into your local :https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js ,

Comment: Jquery? I haven't used that in my code

Comment: clear cache of your browser. It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine  in our machines.

As you said in one comment that you are getting the old files always, it should be `cache problem`

If it is the cache problem, steps to **clear cache** in **chrome**.

```
1) Open Chrome.
2) On your browser toolbar, tap More .
3) Tap History, and then tap Clear browsing data.
4) Under "Clear browsing data," select the checkboxes for Cookies and site data and Cached images and files.
5) Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want to delete. ...
6) Tap Clear browsing data.
```

If you want to remove cached views from the code.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is a link where you get these sort of answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine)

Also you can,

```
1) Open your browser console
2) Go to network tab
3) Refresh the page
4) While refreshing, right click on network tab and click on, clear browser cookies, then press alt+f5
```

Comment: I've tried all the old data was deleted my passwords and all still somehow browser loads mine old file

Comment: old file means? the `html` or the `data`?

Comment: old html and  js file

Comment: open your browser console, go to network tab, refresh the page, and while refreshing, right click on `network tab` and click on, `clear browser cookies`, then press `alt+f5`

Comment: okay great, every time you fave a cache issue, try the steps in above comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sravan

Comment: glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Same code works here

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    var data = {
      book: {
        author: $scope.author,
        title: $scope.title,
        body: $scope.body
      }
    }

    $http.post("/", data).success(function(data, status) {
      console.log('Data posted successfully');
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>


  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-app="myApp">    
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
      Author:
      <input type="text" ng-model="author">
      <br>
      <br> Title:
      <input type="text" ng-model="title">
      <br>
      <br> Body:
      <input type="author" ng-model="body">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit()">
    </form>
  </div>  
</body>
 

</html>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense, rather you should add plunkr in comment, and ask OP for more inputs

Comment: @sajeetharan Does that mean I should try with another file named script.js

Comment: @AbhishekParikh Not necessary see here https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/tc6z0r66/

Comment: @AbhishekParikh check if your angular script file is loaded in the network tab

Comment: 200 file found Angular.min.js

Comment: No I don't have sorry

Comment: My chrome is loading old files instead of new

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129090/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-abhishek-parikh).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this line after your angular.js script line:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
```

it will work..