# Template file is caching, how to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've a simple AngularJS app that looks like:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var userApp = angular.module("userApp", ["ngRoute", "ngSanitize"])
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when("/", {
                controller: "userController",
                controllerAs: "uc",
                templateUrl: window.applicationBaseUrl +  "Angular/UserApp/Template/Index.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/"});
        });
})();
```

The problem is whenever I edit the `Index.html` template file, it doesn't refresh. It seems the template is caching in my chrome browser possible?

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS disable partial caching on dev machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718826/angularjs-disable-partial-caching-on-dev-machine)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome : F12 -> Network tab -> Check disabled cache and try Ctril + F5